# Not able to save entity using spring data jdbc in postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I am trying to save data in postgres using spring data jdbc. i am able to update, get and delete entity but i am not able to save it. took a sample project from internet and I tried to follow spring data example for jdbc, used JdbcAggregateTemplate and the code goes like this for model class. I have searched that jdbc updates any entity instead of directly inserting but how can i insert with using any random generator. and how can i use random generator like we do in jpa.

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;

import com.javabydeveloper.util.UserType;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;


@Data // lomok
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    //private static final long serialVersionUID = -2343243243242432341L;
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Date createdTime;
    private Date updatedTime;
    @Column("DOB") // to map db column if property not same as column name
    private Date dateofBirth;
    private UserType userType; // Enum Type
}
```

repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, WithInsert<User> {
}
```

controller class

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {

        System.out.println(user); // Just to inspect values for demo
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

withInsert interface impl

```
public class WithInsertImpl<T> implements WithInsert<T> {

    
    private final JdbcAggregateTemplate template;

    public WithInsertImpl(JdbcAggregateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }
    
    @Override
    public T insert(T t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return template.insert(t);
    }

}
```

error

```
2021-02-11 13:35:57.729 ERROR 28664 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/usermanager] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute DbAction.UpdateRoot(entity=User(id=1, userName=shelly, password=1234, email=soal@abc.com, createdTime=Thu Feb 11 05:53:25 IST 2021, updatedTime=Thu Feb 11 05:53:25 IST 2021, dateofBirth=null, userType=STUDENT))] with root cause

org.springframework.dao.IncorrectUpdateSemanticsDataAccessException: Failed to update entity [User(id=1, userName=shelly, password=1234, email=soal@abc.com, createdTime=Thu Feb 11 05:53:25 IST 2021, updatedTime=Thu Feb 11 05:53:25 IST 2021, dateofBirth=null, userType=STUDENT)]. Id [1] not found in database.
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.updateWithoutVersion(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:369) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.executeUpdateRoot(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:114) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:70) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.lambda$execute$0(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DefaultAggregateChange.forEachAction(DefaultAggregateChange.java:116) ~[spring-data-relational-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.store(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:339) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:149) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:55) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.javabydeveloper.controller.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:82) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_271]
```

properties for spring-data-source

```
#postgresql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Sample
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=sonal
spring.datasource.platform=postgresql
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
```

Comment: Are you setting the id of the entity to some value before saving?

Comment: No I am not setting it's value anywhere. I used aggregate template and missed to autowire modified repository in serviceImpl class, that's why was not able to insert it. Now it is getting Is there any other way without extending repository interface to insert an entity in table using spring data jdbc?

Comment: I'm willing to bet ... 2cents ... that the id is set, before you call `save`. Please show us the output of `System.out.println(user); // Just to inspect values for demo`

Comment: Ok sorry for misunderstanding. I am setting the value of id, using the POST request body. But Is it not possible to give your own value for id in spring data jdbc using save() method, because using aggregateTemplate.insert(), it is saving the entity in database as expected. I am new in this spring data jdbc, i have worked with spring data jpa and mongo repository before. Am i missing anything in the above defined class?

Answer (score 2):

Spring has a strategy for deciding when the entity is new and insert is required, or the entity is "old" and the update is required. There are more strategies, the first one is deciding upon a value in @Id property of the object.
In your object, `id` is obviously filled with value 1, and therefore an update is triggered (instead of insert).
You should revise your `id` definition, and add something like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 'USER_SEQ')
@SequenceGenerator(name = 'USER_SEQ', sequenceName = 'USER_SEQ', allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;
```

Or some other strategy for handling Id value under the hood. And of course, do not set `id` explicitly with the setter in your source code.

Comment: I am not setting id's value anywhere in the code. I removed the AllArgsConstructor from the code still i faced same issue. Through  aggregateTemplate it was possible to insert but i am not able to to understand why is save method not working to insert a new entity.

Comment: These are JPA or Hibernate annotations, they have no effect what so ever on Spring Data JDBC

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I am hitting the service using POST request and then it is setting the value of id, but is it not possible to give Id value and insert that entity using save() method of CrudRepository using spring data jdbc? it has worked with jparepository and mongodbrepository.